# Headaches with GetWindowRect GetWindowPlacement DwmGetWindowAttribute

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, user32, dwm

I'm a writing window management app in c# winforms to reposition other windows on the desktop.  My issue came when I started using user32.dll calls to get the other windows size and position:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out Rect lpRect);
```

There's 2 problems with this method.

1. Most (but not all) windows the coordinates and size are off by 7 pixels (thanks  dropshadow!), So for example a window at the left of the screen would be actually at -7 instead of 0.
2. Minimized windows are reporting -32000 coordinates.

To solve problem 2 I tried to use:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool GetWindowPlacement(IntPtr hWnd, out WindowPlacement lpwndpl);
```

Using this method we can pull from the WindowPlacment struct the windows normal size when restored, even while it is minimized.  Great!  But it still gives the weird 7 pixel offset from the dropshadow... not so great.

In order to pull the actual size of the window (Problem 1) we can use:

```
[DllImport("dwmapi.dll")]
public static extern int DwmGetWindowAttribute(IntPtr hwnd, int dwAttribute, out Rect pvAttribute, int cbAttribute);
```

By getting the EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS attribute we can pull the correct dimensions of the window without the drop shadow.  But... if the window is minimized we still get coordinates in outer space!

And this is before even trying to solve the problem of scaled windows vs physical screen coordinates.

At the moment the only solution I can think of is to unminimize a window compare it's size with GetWindowRect to the GetWindowPlacement version and store the difference to take into account when moving and repositioning it.  But to say this is a horrible workaround is an understatement.

Surely there's a better way?

Comment: Not entirely sure it makes sense to reposition minimized windows, after al they are minimized

Comment: True but to be clear I'm not trying to mess with minimized windows at all, just need to know their size and position for when they are restored.

Comment: For now my solution was to use GetWindowPlacement and have a checkbox in my app that allows the user to compensate for the drop shadow, simply moving the window left by -7 pixels and adjusting the width by +14 and height by +7 (The same for Windows 10 and 11 thankfully).  It's not the cleanest solution but it works.